# FreeForm Pro, Composer form not displaying Captcha, despite Show for logged_in = YES

Tags: solspace-freeform, captcha

Latest version of FreeForm Pro 4.0.11
Version of EE is 2.4.0 (but I would only upgrade if I really really have to)
Freeform form made with Composer, captcha added. (But it wont appear on fronted)
Tried logging in/out, tried other browser/device as well

Comment: Can you add a summary of your template code. If Anna's answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might need to enable the [**"Require captcha with logged-in members?**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/captcha_preferences.html#require-captcha-with-logged-in-members)" settings in Captcha Preferences.